# ActiveReports - How to have a SubTotal in the GroupHeader

Tags: activereports, subtotal

I need to have the group's subtotal in the header, rather than in the footer as is most commonly done.

I tried a few different settings for the SummaryRunning and SummaryType properties, but it either shows the same as the first detail row, or it's zero.

Is there a way to do this with these properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work in the GroupHeader with the exact same properties as you would use for subtotals in the GroupFooter.

ie

```
SummaryType    = SubTotal
SummaryGroup   = GroupHeader1  
SummaryRunning = None
SummaryFunc    = Sum
```

(replace GroupHeader1 with the name of your GroupHeader)